# how to clear username & password field when user navigate to second screen to the login screen

Tags: android, authentication, android-edittext

I am making a app having login screen.
My question is that if the user installed the application,then if for the first time user entered a username & password and click on login button then user navigate to second activity after that when user click on back button from second activity the username and password is still there in first activity.
How can I clear the edittext field.Any help in this appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
editText.setText("");
```

in your `LoginActivity` `onResume()` method. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Before starting the other activity(when user clicks on login button) you can set the text of both username and password edittext.

```
username.setText("");
password.setText("");
```

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use `editTextUsername.setText("");`
And in your password flied it Automatical clear because you changed inputType to password.